Duplicate image being generated with default name like embedded1.png when using scenario.attach() in cucumber java
I am new to Playwright and cucumber. I have setup a simple project where I am taking a screenshot of the Home Page when login is successful on a website. Screenshot is getting generated in TestScreenshots folder but with 2 screenshots. One is the name which I am giving using Playwright and Second is generated automatically. How to stop Cucumber to auto generate this embedded1.png? I am not able to find the exact issue. I am using Junit4 as runner

Method in Step Class:
@Then("User verifies the Sign In button on the website")
public void user_verifies_the_sign_in_button_on_the_website()  {
        
        assertThat(page.getByRole(AriaRole.BUTTON, new Page.GetByRoleOptions().setName("sign in menu")).first());
        byte[] screenshot=page.screenshot(new Page.ScreenshotOptions()
                  .setPath(Paths.get("./TestScreenshots/Login.png")));
        scenario.attach(screenshot, "image/png", screenshot.toString());
        // scenario.attach(screenshot, "image/png", "Login");--- Giving same issue    
                  
    }

I am using Cucumber Extent Report Adapter 7. Below is my extent.properties file
extent.reporter.spark.start=true
extent.reporter.spark.out=target/Cucumber-Reports/extent-Report.html
extent.reporter.spark.config=src/test/resources/spark-config.xml
screenshot.dir=TestScreenshots/
screenshot.rel.path=../.././TestScreenshots/

RunnerFile:
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
features = "src/test/resources/features",
glue = {"stepdefinitions"},
plugin = {"pretty", "com.aventstack.extentreports.cucumber.adapter.ExtentCucumberAdapter:"})
public class PageRunnerTest {

}

I have tried to debug the issue but did find any solution. Is the extent report causing this issue?

Not your down voter. Nor very familiar with the stack your using, but it does look like you can change the extent configuration to write to a different path. That should allow you to answer your question.

And a 5 min search confirms that screenshot.dir controls where extent writes screenshots. I think you got the down vote for a lack of research.

Screenshots not getting generated is not the issue but the issue is that 2 screenshots is getting generated irrespective of any path I provide.  @M.P.Korstanje

You are using the same path for Extent and Playwright. So it's likely that both write to the same path. If you want to know where the extra screenshots come from you'll want to eliminate extent from the equation. One way would be to make sure they don't write to the same path.
